# R plot errorbars with outliers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get the same aesthetic as below where the error bars look the same and have outliers shown. `geom_errorbar` and `stat_summary` is somewhat similar, but doesn't provide outliers. `geom_boxplot` provide outliers, but the box takes up too much space and I would prefer the slimmed down appearance below. Does anyone know how to achieve this with `ggplot` or without?

[image: graph]

Comment: I'd be really curious about a base R solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can set the width of the boxplot to 0 then use `stat_boxplot` & `stat_summary` to produce the rest of the plot in the picture you added

```r
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0,
               outlier.colour = "red") +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +  
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size = 2) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = 1))  + 
  theme_bw()
p1
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).